# Не могу составить сортировку в sql по группам обращений

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня есть 2 таблицы.
В одной таблице - user_id, relevant_data(жив ли пользователь на сайте 1/0)
В другой таблице user_id, connect_day, reason(a/b/c/d), index_price(цена обращения)

Мне нужно, сделать таблицу на вывод, в котором в первом столбце будет количество обращений, во втором количество пользователей с таким количеством обращений, то сколько они сделали обращений,
Например:

|количество обращений   |количество пользователей |общая стоимость обращений|

```
     1                        5                         5000 руб
     2                        8                         12800 руб
     4                        14                        48000 руб
```

Comment: а, ну и необходимо чтобы relevant_data была 1 и connect day до определенной даты

Comment: Связать, группировать по пользователю, посчитать агрегаты, это использовать как подзапрос для второго уровня агрегирования - по посчитанному количеству.